# Why does std::isnan() return false for double variable with NAN value

Tags: c++, qt

I decided to use `NAN`(also tried `std::numeric_limits::quiet_NaN()`) as default value for argument of the function, but when i tried to check it using `std::isnan`, it returned `false`. In the same time value was printed to console using `qDebug()` and i saw `nan`.

Also i tried to check for `NAN` using `x != x` rule. It worked for `NAN != NAN`, but got `false` for `x != x`.

Last try was to define `NAN` double variable inside of the function and try to check it using both methods, but it lead to the same results.

I cant understand what is wrong.

Example:

```
double abc = NAN;
qDebug()<< abc << (abc != abc) << std::isnan(abc);
```

Output:

```
nan false false
```

Comment: This smells like your compiler defaults to a mode in which it assumes that NaN never happens. Which compiler is it?  Check the documentation for options that enable strict IEEE conformance.

Comment: Try `double abc = 0.0 / 0.0;` and report what happens.

Comment: @Bathsheba Output is the same as in example. Changed `abc = NAN;` to `abc = 0.0 / 0.0;`

Comment: @zwol Compiler - GCC 4.8.4

Comment: Added same strings to another project and got correct output `nan true true`. I'll write a solution when I talk to teamleader.

Comment: @MaximSkvortsov Off-topic, but that compiler is from December 2014.

Comment: what compiler args do you use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't know that we are using `-ffast-math` in our project. That is what leads to the problem. Thank you for your attention and comments. There is no solution if you are using `-ffast-math`. You just need to look for another way to solve your problem (without `NAN`)

Answer (score 4):

`std::optional<double>` would do it, and then at your leisure you could specialize it to use the explicit NAN bit pattern to indicate an unset value. This value would not be passed via FPU registers, and `-ffast-math` would not affect it. Not only would you clearly indicate the intent of an optional argument, but you'd make it compiler-proof :)

Comment: Thank you for answer. It is interesting, but for my purposes `NAN` is not indispensable. I just wanted to understand why does it happen.